# APNS Legacy Support

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

What is the road map for support on the APNS Legacy and enhanced binary interface? (When will it no longer work?) I am currently using PushSharp which appears to use the enhanced binary interface, but does not support the newest interface.

ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/LegacyNotificationFormat.html

Comment: link is dead for legacy format

Comment: @Mikael - I've updated the link, apple moved the content...

Comment: I also couldn't find any info about the roadmap, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

PushSharp 3.x release support the new enhanced binary interface, and in addition, http/2 provider api support is being actively developed.  PushSharp 2.x will be deprecated.

Comment: Redth, thanks for the advisory.  Any roadmap or timeline?  I didn't see one on the site: https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

Comment: No specific timeline. I am waiting for people who are testing it to spend a bit more time without major issues before calling it stable. Probably another week or two.